# How to monitor data inconsistency between cache(redis) and backend database(mysql)

Tags: mysql, caching, redis, monitor

I'm working on a typical web application, doing some CRUD and save changes into mysql database. Now a new redis cache layer on top of mysql DB is added, to improve the performance.

I did some actions to prevent data inconsistency when updating/deleting data, but I cannot 100% guarantee it. So I thought maybe I need some mechanism to monitor any data inconsistency occurrences.

I can write a script to scan data from both redis and mysql and diff them, but I'm hoping to know if there're any other easy ways/tools/best practices to automatically detect any data inconsistency between redis cache and database?

Comment: Why do you need to "monitor" for diffs?  Are you fishing for a bug?  Do you want to inject diffs?  If so, why?  I am curious to hear your results -- how much redis helps in front of MySQL.

Comment: The requirement is to use redis cache to improve query performance. But the scenario I have requires strong consistency. I think a monitor is necessary to detect any inconsistency in time so I can fix the data before it causes too much confusion to users.
If cache is hit, they response time is less than 100ms, but if not hit and DB query is needed, the query time could be around 500ms.

Comment: Let's see one of the 500ms queries -- maybe we can speed it up.